# Анимация перехода между разными фрагментами и активити

Tags: android, анимация

На скринах 2 активити, 2 фрагмента.
В первом - список из ProductView, по нажатию открывается детальная информация во второй активити.
Во второй - ProductView и остальные поля (описание и т.д.)

Можно ли сделать анимацию перехода от списка к детальному представлению?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Я не задаю вопрос без нескольких часов гугления. В сети много примеров переходных анимаций между двумя активити и между двумя фрагментами одной активити. Но не нашел/не увидел примера между двумя фрагментами разных активити

Comment: Да, и, возможно, неточно задан вопрос. Нужна transition animation, когда создается впечатление, что карточка товара в первой и второй активити - одно и то же.